# All bounded measurable functions with $\int_1^2 x^n f(x) dx=0, n=0,1,2...$?

Tags: real-analysis

Find all real valued bounded measurable functions $f(x)$ such that $\int_1^2 x^n f(x) dx=0$ for $n=0,1,2...$.

Answer (score 1):

The only Borel mesure $\mu$ on $[1,2]$ such that $\int gd\mu=0$ for all continuous functions $g$ is the zero measure. Use Wierstrass Theorem to conclude that $f(x)dx$ is the zero measure and hence $f=0$ almost everywhere (and conversely).